# Bitwise packing/unpacking - generalized solution for arbitrary values

Tags: javascript, java, bitwise-operators, bit-packing

I'm trying to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557022/2118955) to arbitrary numeric values.

Let's say we have 3 (unsigned) numbers:

`v1`, `v2`, `v3`

and we know the respective max values they may have:

`max1`, `max2`, `max3`.

`max1 * max2 * max3 < 2^32`,

so the result (packed value) is to be within 32 bits.

How to pack/unpack them without "magic" hardcoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly different way to do it.

```
int max1 = 1000;
int max2 = 500;
int max3 = 500;
```

shift values determined based on most significant set bit of maximums.

```
int size1 = 32-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(max1);
int size2 = 32-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(max2);
int size3 = 32-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(max3);
```

mask values determined by complementing -1 shifted size bits.

```
int mask1 = ~(-1<<size1);
int mask2 = ~(-1<<size2);
int mask3 = ~(-1<<size3);

int v1 = 934;
int v2 = 293;
int v3 = 349;
```

Nothing really new here. Second shift shifts both first and second values.

```
int packed = (((v3<<size2)|v2)<<size1)|v1;
```

Now reverse it

```
v1 = packed&mask1;
// this saves the shifted packed version for the next step
v2 = (packed = packed>>>size1)&mask2;
v3 = (packed>>>size2)&mask3;
        
System.out.println(v1);
System.out.println(v2);
System.out.println(v3);
```

Prints

```
934
293
349
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the numbers be packed in the same order like in the referenced answer, from right to left starting with `v1`:

```
v3 <- v2 <- v1
```

We already have a solution from the referenced answer, but it only works for specific case (source data):

```
// packing:
packed = (v3 << 8) | (v2 << 7) | v1;

// unpacking:
v1 = packed & 0x7F;
v2 = (packed >> 7) & 1;
v3 = (packed >> 8);
```

The code above uses the following magic constants:

- `7` (`size1`) - size in bits to allocate the 1st number (`v1`).
- `1` (`size2`) - ...(similarly) for the 2st number (`v2`). Note that this constant is used above implicitly: `8 = 7 + 1`.
- `0x7F` (`sample1`) - sample value to be used in bitwise comparison to unpack the 1st number (`v1`).
- `1` (`sample2`) - ...(similarly) for the 2st number (`v2`).

In order to get a general solution it's enough to generalize the above constants. Let's name them `size1`, `size2`, `sample1` and `sample2` respectively. Below are their general definitions:

```
size1 = Math.floor(Math.log(max1) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
size2 = Math.floor(Math.log(max2) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
sample1 = Math.pow(2, size1 + 1) - 1;
sample2 = Math.pow(2, size2 + 1) - 1;
```

So with these constants the general solution should look like this:

```
// packing:
packed = v3 << (size1 + size2) | v2 << size1 | v1;

// unpacking:
v1 = packed & sample1;
v2 = (packed >> size1) & sample2;
v3 = packed >> (size1 + size2);
```